# Get absolute file path of certain file type in CWD

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I use the python program cclib under Windws to process some *.log files that reside in subfolders and sometimes even subsubfolders of Z:\dir1.
I have copied my .py script to each subfolder where a *.log file exists by help of a DOS script.

There I want to execute this simple .py script:

```
from cclib.io import ccopen
p = ccopen("*opt.NORMAL.log")
data = p.parse()
homo = data.homos[0] # assuming spin-restricted
lumo = homo + 1

homo_energy = data.moenergies[0][homo]
lumo_energy = data.moenergies[0][lumo]

print (homo_energy, lumo_energy)
```

However directing ccopen (all off cclibs .py scripts relevant for this lie in my C:\py35 folder) to the *.log file in the current working directory where I executed this script doesn't work out (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parse').
Ccopen seems to require the absolute path to my *.log, at least it works if I paste that in.
With my DOS script I pass recursively through every sub and subsub of Z:\dir1  containing a *.log file but with different name. In each of this directories I execute my py script. How do I tell the ccopen module in my script to process the *.log file in the current working directory?

I guess this kind of question has been asked a thousand times but I just couldn't find the right solution. So, sorry for duplicate and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

you could change your line

```
ccopen("*opt.NORMAL.log")
```

by a call to `glob.glob` to resolve the filename, with a check just in case there would be no or many files matching the wildcard pattern

```
files = glob.glob("*opt.NORMAL.log")
if len(files)==1:
   p = ccopen(files[0])
else:
   raise Exception("Expected 1 log file, found {}".format(len(files)))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I seem to have gotten wrong identation or something. Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting the error   File "homolumoscript.py", line 29

              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: sorry, parenthesis missing. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that now as well. Thank you very much for helping!